# Is it possible to use a service with a generic type in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have used generics in other languages extensively. I would like to use it in Typescript as well.

I created an Angular service with generic parameters. However, my current code doesn't work. Is there a way to make this work? My current code is as follows:

IUpdater:

```
export interface IUpdater {
  update(): void;
}
```

Updater service:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class ExampleUpdaterService implements IUpdater {
  update(): void {
    // Other code
  }
}
```

Generic service:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class GenericService<TService extends IUpdater> {

  constructor(private service: TService) { }

  // Other code
}
```

In this configuration, I want to register the generic service like following:

```
@Component({
  /* Stuff */
})
export class TdeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private updaterService: GenericService<ExampleUpdaterService>) { }
}
```

Comment: can u provide code example in stackblitz ?

Comment: @SyedMohammadFahimAbrar I didn't provide a stackblitz because this is something I do not know how to do. I don't even know if this is possible. That is why I am asking the question in the first place. Notice the question starts with "Is it possible" and continues with what I have tried. Should I have added a non-working stackblitz?

Comment: Can you tell me if this cover ur answer? https://pastebin.com/J67p5jTv if yes I will post an answer.

Comment: @SyedMohammadFahimAbrar The problem I am having is that knowing the type of model class is not enough for me to send an update request. The line `return http.post(content);` is an oversimplification. Here, I need to call a service method.